# Why mobile navbar doesn't scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

My navbar doesn't scroll when I resize to a small website. my lower menu disappear and can not scroll down to see lower menu so need to resize to fullscreen for see others. So I want my site can scroll when height is less than full screen.
like this in pictures others D menu disappear.
[image]
[image]
here is my code :

```js
const body = document.querySelector("body");
const navbar = document.querySelector(".navbarr");
const menuBtn = document.querySelector(".menu-btn");
const cancelBtn = document.querySelector(".cancel-btn");
menuBtn.onclick = ()=>{
  navbar.classList.add("show");
  menuBtn.classList.add("hide");
  body.classList.add("disabled");
}
cancelBtn.onclick = ()=>{
  body.classList.remove("disabled");
  navbar.classList.remove("show");
  menuBtn.classList.remove("hide");
}
window.onscroll = ()=>{
  this.scrollY > 20 ? navbar.classList.add("sticky") : navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
}
```

```css
.navbarr{
  padding-top: 85px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  background: #ffffff;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;

}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;

}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  }
.navbarr.sticky{
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: px 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.navbarr .content{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.navbarr .logo a{
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navbarr .menu-list{
  display: inline-flex;
}
.menu-list li{
  list-style: none;
}
.menu-list li a{
  color: #000000;
  margin-left: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.icon{
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}
.menu-list .cancel-btn{
  position: absolute;
  right: 80px;
  top: 110px;
}
@media (max-width: 1230px) {
  .content{
    padding: 0 60px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1100px) {
  .content{
    padding: 0 40px;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .content{
    padding: 0 40px;
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-right: 0%;
  }
  .menu-list .cancel-btn{
    position: absolute;
    right: 50px;
    top: 110px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  body.disabled{
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .icon{
    display: block;
  }
  .icon.hide{
    display: none;
  }
  .navbarr .menu-list{
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    right: -100%;
    top: 0px;
    display: block;
    padding: 100px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
  .navbarr.show .menu-list{
    right: 0%;
  }
  .navbarr .menu-list li{
    margin-top: 45px;
  }
  .navbarr .menu-list li a{
    font-size: px;
    margin-right: -100%;
  }
  .navbarr.show .menu-list li a{
    margin-right: 0px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .dropdown-content {
    position: initial;
  }
  .dropdown-content a {
    padding: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbarr">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="" width="80" height="80" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
      <ul class="menu-list">
        <div class="icon cancel-btn">
          <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
        </div>
        <li><a href="a.html">A</a></li>
        <li><a href="b.html">B</a></li>     
        <li><a href="c.html">C</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="D" class="dropbtn">D</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">D01</a>
              <a href="#">D02</a>
              <a href="#">D03</a>
              <a href="#">D04</a>
              <a href="#">D05</a>
              <a href="#">D06</a>
              <a href="#">D07</a>
            </div>
            </li>
        <li><a href="F.html">F</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="icon menu-btn">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]Because you have used `position: sticky;` which preventing it to be scrolled just consider replacing position sticky in media query.

There is issue in positioning and structure.The menu-list covered here is given in image. Using proper div structure will help you out.

Comment: because sticky prevents form moving up https://contentsquare.com/blog/the-3-golden-rules-of-sticky-menu-navigation/ this may help you out . Sticky would be fine for small menu but in your case sticky will not work fine.just check out anyway nice responsive.

Comment: I deleted position: sticky; but it not working